# How to embed unembedded fonts in PDF with Python

Tags: python, pdf, ghostscript

Did some searching, came across [this](https://reachtim.com/articles/PDF-Testing.html) to recognize fonts that aren't embedded but are referenced in a PDF.
I need to re-create the PDF having them embedded.

I have looked at recreating the PDF with Py2PDF2 or [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw) but neither of them have an option to embed fonts.

Does anybody know of a solution? I don't need pure Python.
Alternatively I could start trying to read about the PDF format and try to create a font embed-er myself, but that seems daunting / too big for my current Python/programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you have the fonts available, then you could use Ghostscript to create a new PDF file. You would need to make the fonts available to Ghostscript, which means creating appropriate font records. Ghostscript has documentation on how to do this, but it does require some effort and possibly some experimentation to get correct.

You haven't supplied an example PDF file so I can't be specific, but PDF files can contain both Fonts and CIDFonts. CIDFonts are supposed to **always** be embedded but unfortunately some creators ignore that. TrueType fonts, and particularly CIDFonts with TrueType outlines, are harder to create substitute records for than regular Fonts, but a reasonable degree of success is possible, particularly with Latin languages. Note that if a font is unavailable, and you tell the pdfwrite device to embed all fonts, then it may embed a wildly incorrect font, such as Helvetica, while calling it by the name of the missing font.

The PDF format is reasonably complicated, as are font formats, unless you are already conversant with both technologies its going to be a big job to write a tool to embed fonts (actually it'll be a big job even if you are conversant with them).

Much depends on the way the PDF file was created, and the fonts used.